# No connection to NAS with a Router

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, nas

I have following Network Devices

- **InternetBox:** VDSL Modem+Router 2in1 (4x LAN + WLAN)

  *IP  (192.168.1.1) - Located in Basement*
- **Router:** Netgear WNDR3700v5 Router (4x LAN + 1WAN + WLAN)

  *IP   (192.168.0.1)* wich is connected to the InternetBox via LAN - Located in 2nd Floor
- **NAS:** Synology DS214 (1x LAN)

  *IP  DHCP(192.168.1.113)* if its connected to InternetBox

  *IP  DHCP(192.168.0.4)* if its connected to the Router

---

When I connect the NAS to the Internet Box, everything works fine. But when I connect the NAS to the Router, only devices that directly connectet to the Router has access to the NAS.

But I'd like to get access from every devices in my house.

I've tried to change the NAS's IP manually to the Internet xBox's IP(Gateway ect.) but it doesn't work.

Can someone give me Hint, what am I doing wrong? Please note: I'm a beginner.

Comment: You would need to set up NAT port forwarding rules on the netgaear if you wish to access the NAS from a box outside the 192.168.0.x network. Don't change any of the IP settings on the NAS itself (at least not to fix this problem).

Comment: Why do you have two LANs? Is there some reason for this setup? It creates all kinds of problems because the "inner" LAN now has double NAT.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  - I don't know if its correct, but in the 2nd Floor the Wifi Signal is too weak and I have one Desktop and a NAS I'd like to connect thru LAN and Smartphones tru Wifi

Comment: That's a good reason to have more than one access point for your LAN. But is there some reason you have two LANs? If not, why not change the configuration so you only have one LAN and all these annoying problems will go away.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't need two LANs. Is there a way to programm my Netgear WNDR3700v5 Router as an accsess point, without having to LAN's?

Comment: @StackUnderflow Yes: 1) Don't use its WAN port. 2) Disable its DHCP server. 3) Assign its LAN interface an IP address inside the range for your LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your network description as this:

[image: Network diagram]

Note that your router here has at least two network interfaces. One on the 'blue network' and one on the 'green network'. These are two separate networks.

If you connect the NAS to the 'Internet box' then it will need an IP in the 192.168.1.0/24 range. This IB knows how to reach devices on it local (green) network. If it is not on the known list then it tries to access them via the default gateway. (In your case the route to the Internet).

Unless told it does not know about the blue network! It should not be able to reach any devices on that blue network untill you add a route. (See 
https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work for more explanation on IPv4 and routing). However your router might actually understand routing and do something helpful here,

Now if you connect the NAS to the blue network then it is on the same network as all other devices on the blue network. All of these can reach it, but devices directly connected to the green network should not know about it. Not until you add a route for it. Just how you do that depends on your device. For many linux like distributions it would be something like `route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth0`. For many consumer devices it might be something done via GUI.  Without more information we can not tell.

PS: I assumed your router is an actual router and that you are not using a double NAt or something equally ugly.